# Does HTTP response follow same path as HTTP request?

Tags: http, networking

Supose i have a load balancer then 2 web servers again a load balancer then 4 app servers.

Does HTTP response follow the same path as HTTP request to serve?

Comment: There was a paper in the 1980s which showed that 40% of Internet connections used different forward and reverse paths.

Answer (score 1):

By path, I assume you been the routing path between nodes in your network.

The response of an HTTP request is sent back to the client via an open TCP connection on the server, typically the same one used to send the request. Whether it takes the same path depends on the configuration of your network. In most cases it would take the same path within your network behind the load balancer. However, this isn't universally guaranteed.